# Datefield in grid editor

Tags: javascript, extjs, format, datefield

I have this code

```
{
                xtype: 'datecolumn',                    
                dataIndex: 'fechaNacimiento',
                itemId: 'fechaNacimiento',
                flex: 1,
                //hidden: true,
                //hideable: false,
                text: 'Fecha de Nacimiento',
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    format: 'd/m/Y',
                    allowBlank:false,
                }
            },
```

Date is set in the grid as the format defined 'd/m/Y' 03/06/2018, but when I am trying to send that date to data base the format changes to '2018-03-06T00:00:00'.

I also set my model like this:

```
{name: 'fechaNacimiento', mapping: 'FECHA_NACIMIENTO', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'd/m/Y'}
```

I need to send the date in format: 'd/m/Y'. just like this: 03/06/2018

anyone knows why date is changing and how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Why does the format in the DB matter to you? You can reformat it however you want when using it...

Comment: Because I am trying to insert a new row in the grid and when I am sending data to the Store Procedure, date is sent like that so the Store Procedure sent me a message error because the date format is not correct. I don´t have access to data base. I just send data to the sp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`convert`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-convert) config for model fields. Inside `convert` config you can return your desired output.

A function which converts the value provided by the Reader into the value that will be stored in the record. This method can be overridden by a derived class or set as a [`convert`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-convert) config.

If configured as `null`, then no conversion will be applied to the raw data property when this Field is read. This will increase performance. but you must ensure that the data is of the correct type and does not need converting.

Example of convert functions:

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name', {
        name: 'joindate',
        convert: function(value, record) {
            //if value is not defined then null return
            return value ? Ext.Date.format(value, 'd/m/Y') : null;
        }
    }]
});
```

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2e0a)**, I have created a demo using `grid`, `cellediting` and `datefiled`. I hope this will help/guid you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        Ext.define('MyModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['name', {
                name: 'joindate',
                convert: function (value, r) {
                    //if value is not defined then null return
                    return value ? Ext.Date.format(value, 'd/m/Y') : null;
                }
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'myStore',
            model: 'MyModel',
            data: [{
                name: 'Lisa'
            }, {
                name: 'Bart'
            }, {
                name: 'Homer'
            }, {
                name: 'Marge'
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'My Data',
            store: 'myStore',
            columns: [{
                header: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                flex: 1,
                editor: 'textfield'
            }, {
                header: 'Join Date',
                dataIndex: 'joindate',
                //You can also use Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d/m/Y') for showing required date formate inside grid cell.
                // renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d/m/Y'),
                flex: 1,
                editor: {
                    completeOnEnter: false,
                    field: {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        editable: false,
                        //The date format string which will be submitted to the server. The format must be valid according to Ext.Date#parse.
                        submitFormat: 'd/m/Y',
                        //The default date format string which can be overriden for localization support. The format must be valid according to Ext.Date#parse.
                        format: 'd/m/Y',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
                }
            }],
            selModel: 'cellmodel',
            plugins: {
                ptype: 'cellediting',
                clicksToEdit: 1
            },
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            tools: [{
                type: 'plus',
                handler: function () {
                    var grid = this.up('grid'),
                        store = grid.getStore(),
                        rec = Ext.create('MyModel', {
                            name: ''
                        }),
                        context;

                    store.add(rec);

                    //Get Ext.grid.CellContext of first cell using getColumns()[0]
                    context = grid.getView().getPosition(rec, grid.getColumns()[0])

                    //Start editing in first cell
                    grid.setActionableMode(true, context);
                }
            }],
            bbar: ['->', {
                text: 'Save Data',
                handler: function (btn) {
                    var store = this.up('grid').getStore();
                    store.each(rec => {
                        console.log(rec.data);
                    })
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```